# Excel solver with if statements

Tags: excel, solver

I am trying an optimization problem with solver. One of the conditions has to to be :

```
if A=1 then B and or C = 1
```

I am trying to avoid the specific combination where all of the following are true:

- `A=1`
- `B=0`
- `C=0`

I tried `A*10+B+C /= 10`, but solver does not have an unequal constraint either.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you trying to write an Excel formula?

Comment: I know I can use IF and or in Excel, but it seems to not work with the excel build in solver, so I have to find a way around that limitation

Comment: So you are trying to make an equation that will be 1 or 0 but without using IF? Can you use AND or OR or just arithmetic?

Comment: Also, are you saying that if A = 1, then either B, C, or both B and C are equal to -1?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that clarified the conditions. But could you add whether you're able to use AND or OR or any other operators?

Answer (score 0):

Have cell D that has the calculation that is B+C, set a constraint in the solver that that cell must be equal to 1. Or greater than or equal to 1 - not sure as you don’t clarify all states of b & c...

Then add a constraint that A must be less or equal to D.

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine a truth table to your function you are going to get something like this:

A B C f

0   0   0   0

...

1   0   0   1

...

1   1   1   0

So we can use boolean logic operators and crate the following equivalent representation:

True on f = A and Not(B) and Not(C)

This formula return true only if A=1, B=0, C=0 and false in any other way.
Translate it to binary representation:

True is 1, false is 0, and is *, or is +, not L is (1-L)

And you get:

f = A*(1-B)*(1-C)

If you run into some more complicated conditions, you can make a complex expression. Draw your truth table, constract a similar 'ands' expression for each row where f = 1, and put an 'or' between them. Like this:
(A and Not(B) and C) or (not(A), not(B), C) or ...   .

There are more efficient ways of doing this, efficient in sense of producing shorter  boolean expressions. If it is important to you then you should have a look on Karnaugh maps technique. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map
(I think the wiki article is a bit too complex for this simple operation. Maybe a YouTube example will demonstrate this better)

Otherwise it should really cover everything you need :)